# React TypeScript: Correct type for dynamic path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

The router looks somthing like this

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

...
<Route exact path='/confirm-email/:confirmationCode' component={ConfirmEmail} />
                                        ^
//                                      This is the value that gets passed to the props
```

And the component that gets loaded is

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
  confirmationCode: string;
}
const ConfirmEmail: React.FC<PropsInterface>  = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  const confirmationCode = props.match.params.confirmationCode;
                                                   ^
//                                                 Error Here!
```

The error I get is `Property 'confirmationCode' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

This is not a duplicate of [react-router-dom with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118060/react-router-dom-with-typescript) as it does not address the dynamic path being passed as a prop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router-dom with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118060/react-router-dom-with-typescript)

Comment: It shows how to attach an interface but doesn't show the correct type for the props when passing a dynamic path

Comment: `the correct type for the props when passing a dynamic path ` This phrase is not valid? What do you mean by that?  create another interface that extends `RouteComponentProps` and define other props in there? Or pass specific Route props as `<TParams>`

Comment: I edited the question to try and make the issue more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:confirmationCode` is part of the Route props, `props.match.params.confirmationCode`

So a prop that belongs to `RouteComponentProps`

Therefore you need to pass it to RouteComponentProps like:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps<{confirmationCode: string}> {
 others:any; // Other props that belong to component it self not Router
}
```

or more clear if you want to destruct more Route params

```
   interface IParams { confirmationCode:string; ....  }
   interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps<IParams>{....}
```

SO you see this is exactly the same as what is covered in the duplicated question? the differences are namings.